# android.widget.TextView vs TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

Both of them link to the same TextView.java file and looks the same on design tab. The question is, when I should use the short one `<TextView ... />` and when the long one `<android.widget.TextView />`

Can I use, for example `<ConstraintLayout>` instead of `<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>` (both link to the same ConstraintLayout.class but looks different on design tab), and how do I know how to use the widgets and other "components" from [android reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText)

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to default widgets you find in the `android.view` and `android.widget` packages of the *Android* framework, you can ommit the package name, as it's implicitly searched anyhow.

Since the `ConstraintLayout` is not a default widget, you cannot ommit the package name with it.

Additionally to the default widget packages, *AndroidX* replaces the inflater components resolving the actual classes, thus `<TextView>` actually resolves to `AppCompatTextView` instead, so better don't use the quallified name of the class like `<android.widget.TextView>`.

Comment: What is the definition for "default widgets"?

Comment: Everythign which is shipped with the _Android_ framework within `android.view` or `android.widget`.

Comment: It is simply everything that comes with the basic project setup without any additional dependencies for view components  added. They form the basic components on which you can build additional and more complex ones according to your need

Answer (score 1):

`<TextView />` and `<android.widget.TextView />` are the same. You can use it interchangeably because they are part of the basic components of Android.
However, in case in of ConstraintLayout it comes as a part of the support library that you added to to the build.gradle file in your app.  To access a class from that you need to fully tell the xml that you want ConstraintLayout from that specific package.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is when I should use the short one `<TextView ... />` and when the long one `<android.widget.TextView />`

Both are the same things you can use any one , Better to use `<TextView ... />`  as most developers use it and it's less code to write .

> Can I use for example `<ConstraintLayout>` instead of  `<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`

No you can't it does not come with default in android  , you have to use a separate  support library to use it `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'`

> how do I know how to use the widgets and other "components" from android reference

Any thing with package `android.widget.xxxx` or `android.view.xxxx` use `xxxx` directly for others use full package name in layout .

You can see the classes which comes under android widget over [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary#classes) and classes which comes under android view over [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary#classes)